# How to carry kitchenware when traveling interstate through buses/trains?

Tags: luggage, packing

Essentially title. What would be the best way to carry the required for cooking when travelling interstate? I am talking about items like knives, pots and so on.

Putting them directly in the luggage bag with clothes seems a bit awakard due to their shapes and sizes.

Comment: This will probably vary a lot depending on how many and what kind, and also how you are travelling (car, bus, train, flight…). And possibly how often you are moving from place to place.

Comment: If you're flying, you'll have to clear security, which will generally not allow any dangerous or might-be-dangerous items (such as knives) in carry-on baggage.

Comment: Most places that provide stoves and other kitchen things also supply the pots and the knives. I am having trouble imagining why you would need to bring those to someone else's kitchen, or what use they would be without a kitchen.

Comment: It's a little unclear what kind of kitchenware we're talking about here. There is a lot of cooking gear made for camping and backpacking that's intended to be more easily packable (the ultra-light backpacking gear also often comes at a high price in exchange for its lightness, which may or may not be relevant to your needs). But recommendations of that sort aren't really appropriate if you're moving your home. So what kind of cooking equipment do you need to carry, where's it going, and in what situations do you need to use it where the basics aren't already provided?

Comment: @KateGregory I've camped in a few places where there was a firepit  with a grate over it, but no cooking gear to use with it.  I was hiking or driving then.  I've carried enough to make a cold meal (little more than a picnic), and I've stayed in a motel that had a fridge and microwave in the room, but no cooking equipment.  So a few basic camping-style items might make some sense, but not a kitchen's worth.

Comment: assuming camping kitchenware, those are usually meant to be packed, so, not really an issue at all. Assuming other types, I'm not sure what the point is?

Answer (score 2):

When I travel with cooking equipment it's usually rather minimal, and I do pack it in my normal luggage, with clothes etc. Both weight and number of pieces of luggage are constrained then. The trick here is to pack flexible things around awkward things. The exception is that a lot of my travel is by camper van, where the cooking stuff is stowed in the kitchen cupboards.

When moving home, or transporting larger quantities to run events it's a different matter. Then I pack it in plastic crates or cardboard boxes, with the fragile things protected against impacts, and sharp knives wrapped in fairly strong fabric of some sort, such as tea towels (dish towels).

Answer (score 0):

Invest in a travel cooking set with a compact and lightweight design, or pack your kitchen items in a separate bag designated for cooking gear. Alternatively, wrap your cooking gear in towels or soft materials before packing them tightly and securely. You could also ship your kitchen items ahead of time to avoid carrying bulky and potentially dangerous items during your travels.